# Use Type.GetType() to get the type and how to new an object in this typical type?

Tags: c#, types, createinstance

```
 Type typesample = packet.GetType();
```

Then I want to new an object in the type of typesample

Comment: Try use `Activator` class

Comment: We want your tries also. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the type by using the Activator class:

```
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(typesample);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typesample);
```